# Consequences of Not Eating Enough Fruits and Vegtables?

Tags: weight-loss, diet, eating-habits, fruit, vegetables

I have never really eaten many vegetables; maybe a few every fortnight (two weeks). I do always manage about 3 pieces of fruit every week.

I have recently changed my life style and now eating healthy and exercising and have daily smoothies with kale, spinach, blue berries, strawberries, black berries, raspberries, banana, etc.

What health benefits would I see from increasing my fruit and veg intake? and what are the consequences of not eating fruit & vegetables?

Comment: One would be in a better position to answer if also mention what you are eating daily? What is you weight , height? goal?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply google the health benefit of each of the fruits/vegetables. Those would be the benefits of consuming those fruits/vegetables.

About the consequences of not eating them, *(assuming you aren't obtaining the same nutrients from other sources)*, you'll be deficient in those nutrients as well.

*I would tell you the health benefits of each fruit, but that would just spoil the fun; wouldn't you agree?*  :)